# How to query the records contain double byte characters in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In SqlServer, we have 1 table--Product. Some of its records contains both double byte characters (like Chinese) and single byte characters(like English). The question is how to query those records which contains double byte characters. Thank you very much.

Comment: I assume your columns are `char` and `nchar`.  You can query both like any other column; what's the problem?  Could you add a code snippet?

Comment: You might be able to do something like: SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName NOT LIKE '[a-Z]%%' But I would only use them to find how many there are of that kind etc, not to use it in app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine varchar content in nvarchar columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283955/determine-varchar-content-in-nvarchar-columns)

Answer (score 6):

Based on my understanding of the question, assuming you have an NVARCHAR column that you are looking at, you could try this example:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (Field1 NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT @Data VALUES ('ABC')
INSERT @Data VALUES ('123')
INSERT @Data VALUES (N'Value with 化ける unicode chars in')

SELECT * FROM @Data WHERE Field1 <> CAST(Field1 AS VARCHAR(100))
```

So this is going to return all records where the VARCHAR (non-unicode) representation does not match the NVARCHAR value - e.g. if the value contains unicode characters, then the VARCHAR representation will not match and hence will return the row

Comment: I want to add one more thing, In this situation, OP must add 'N before the search expression. Correct ?

Comment: @SQL - no, example should work exactly as I've written for this scenario

Comment: +1. I answered similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1283955/27535 Basicaly, rely on the conversion to detect loss of data

Comment: The scenario you mentioned is correct. Please have a look at my response for more clarity of my question.

Answer (score 3):

1. The column should be of type **nvarchar** and not **varchar** (or nchar for char)
2. You should use `N'` at the start of search string containing such characters. N'TestćšString'
3. IN the code behind use nvacrahr as parameter type.

Example query

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE YourColumnName = N'TestćšString'
```

Check the difference between below statements.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (Field1 NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT @Data VALUES ('ABC')
INSERT @Data VALUES ('123')
INSERT @Data VALUES (N'Value with 化ける unicode chars in')

SELECT * FROM @Data WHERE Field1  = N'Value with 化ける unicode chars in'



DECLARE @Data TABLE (Field1 NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT @Data VALUES ('ABC')
INSERT @Data VALUES ('123')
INSERT @Data VALUES (N'Value with 化ける unicode chars in')

SELECT * FROM @Data WHERE Field1  = 'Value with 化ける unicode chars in'
```

Comment: 1. The column will already be nvarchar to hold DBCS 2. The N prefix isn't needed for this problem. Your points are valid otherwise: but the question is about "how to find DBCS in an nvarchar field"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to identify non-ASCII text. It works because pure ASCII is the only overlap between Thai, Japanese, Hebrew and Code Page 437.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsAscii(@text nvarchar(max))
    RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
        CASE WHEN EXISTS
            (
                SELECT CAST(@text AS varbinary(max)) [bin]
                INTERSECT
                SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST(@text COLLATE Hebrew_BIN
                    AS varchar(max)) AS nvarchar(max)) AS varbinary(max))
                INTERSECT
                SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST(@text COLLATE Thai_BIN2
                    AS varchar(max)) AS nvarchar(max)) AS varbinary(max))
                INTERSECT
                SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST(@text COLLATE Japanese_BIN2
                    AS varchar(max)) AS nvarchar(max)) AS varbinary(max))
                INTERSECT
                SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST(@text collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN2
                    AS varchar(max)) AS nvarchar(max)) AS varbinary(max))
            )
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
END
GO
```