# SQL Server get Chinese text from a string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column that contains the part name in both English and Chinese.

For example "Screw with washer-玻璃板螺丝"

How do I extract the Chinese name from that string in SQL Server? Is it even possible?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Its always "<some english><some chinese>" ?

Comment: 90% of the time it's English "-" Chinese. Some instances the user forgets to add the "-"

Comment: Unless there is a fixed pattern, then this isn't efficient in T-SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumes Chinese is *always* at the end

```
DECLARE @orig nvarchar(100) = N'Screw with washer-玻璃板螺丝'

SELECT REPLACE(@orig, REPLACE(CAST(@orig AS varchar(100)), '?', ''), '')
```

Comment: @podiluska: related trick that also relies on lossy conversions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1283971/27535

Comment: @podiluska: yes. `english-chinese-english` will change to `english--english` on conversion. Which won't replace. You'd have to loop char by char.. or something horrible

Comment: @Alex: can you add more test data and your actual SQL then. my sample works

Comment: @gbn - but it would work with chinese-english, i think, and an additional replace (*, '-','') would work with english-chinese-english?

Comment: @podiluska: my solution works where there are 2 blocks. EN-CN or CN-EN. As for 3 blocks, hmmm, don't think so

Comment: @gbn Thanks. It worked for EN-CHI. But of course some users decided to add EN-CHI-EN. Oh well they will have to live with it. But thank you for your help +1

Comment: What if there's an actual ? mark in the text, this will replace that too, doesn't seems like full proof solution