# Restore saved data as text while it should be ntext

Tags: stored-procedures, unicode, sql-server-2008-r2, restore, ntext

I've a database on SQL Server 2008 R2. In a table there's a column that should be with type ntext but it was designed as a text column. So the data was sent, saved as text then it was saved as question marks (unrecognized).

I've changed the type to ntext. Is there's a way to restore back this saved data? I thought about tracking the captured data that was sent to the stored procedure and maintain it manually, but I searched and found no result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

No, the data is lost unless you have the original data. Once written to a non-unicode column, unicode data will be lost. This is demonstrated in my answer here: [Determine varchar content in nvarchar columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1283955/27535)

Also note that [`ntext` is deprecated. You should use `nvarchar(max)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

> ntext , text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.